# runOnUiThread updates wrongly

Tags: android

While update UI using runOnUiThread new value is replaced old value.

```
@Override
    public void onBackgroundRequestCompleted(final String layoutID) {

        ((Activity) ctContext)
                .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        reDesignLayout(layoutID);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Here `layoutID` will be get from server. I will send 10 to 40 request at a time. So 40 response will be received in sequence. But the problem is when 1 response received runOnUiThread will start. before it completes it work I will receive 2nd response. So what happening is `redesingLayout()` receives 2nd layout id instead of 1st layout id. It is happening for multiple times. So UI is not updated fully. Can any one give idea to solve the issue?

Thank you @Maxim Firsoff. Implemented your idea and issue solved. I added the code for future use..!!

```
private Queue<String> LayoutsToRedesign = new LinkedList<>();
    @Override
    public void onBackgroundRequestCompleted(final String layoutID) {

        gridsToRedesign.add(layoutID);

        ((Activity) ctContext)
                .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String layoutIdToDesign = gridsToRedesign.peek();

                        gridsToRedesign.remove(layoutIdToDesign);

                        reDesignLayout(layoutIdToDesign);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: You can trigger the `onBackgroundRequestCompleted()` callback only when the last request is handled, and then serially call `reDesignLayout()` on all requests

Comment: As @Zain pointed that is one option or you can devise some method to make the 2nd request call once you are done with `reDesignLayout()` of the first.

Comment: That's how multithreading works. You ask for something to be executed "later". Nobody knows what that "later" might be. If you need a specific order, you need to ensure it yourself. On a side note: doing 40 layouts at once usually is a bad idea on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Some strategies:

- "takeLast", drops all incoming values and takes only the last one for `reDesignLayout`;
- "takeFirst", is the same as above, but takes the first value;
- "serial", collects all values in a queue, execute reDesignLayout while the queue isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks.. Your idea works. But sometimes I am getting `ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966)`.. I added my code in my question.

Comment: If possible please answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809639/update-layouts-while-scroll-the-nested-scrollview) question also.

Comment: ConcurrentModificationException: please use concurrent structures, because you have a multi-threading access to the data. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html